# how to add a uiscrollview in IB

Tags: iphone, interface-builder, uiscrollview

how is it possible to add an image to be set inside an uiscrollview using just interface builder and no code. i tried simply adding an image into the scrollview and it didnt work. i know this is a really simple answer however i didnt find any IB related help on achieving this

Answer (score 4):

You can add the image to the scroll view in Interface Builder, but in order for it to scroll (even if the image is larger than the scroll view) you need to manually set the scroll view's contentSize property in code, as I am not aware of any way to set this property in Interface Builder.  In your view controller's viewDidLoad method, you can add something like:

```
scrollView.contentSize = imageView.frame.size;
```

Only one line of code, shouldn't be too much trouble.

Comment: I would only add that the contentSize need to be bigger than the UIScrollView's frame size as you have it defined in IB.  Else, all the content will already be in the visible frame and no scrolling is enabled.

Comment: thanks ill use this but i wouldnt to add my scroll view in the header and .m file in order for your line of code to work. ill just try this i though there could be a ib way of doing this automatically thanks :)

Comment: self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, 660); // add in any number for more up/down play

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively as other people have suggested you can create a custom subclass of `UIScrollView`. Then overided initWithCoder:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder 
{
self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
if (self) {

    if ([self.subviews count] > 0) {
        UIView* subview = [self.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
        self.contentSize = subview.frame.size;

        self.alwaysBounceHorizontal = NO;
        self.alwaysBounceVertical = YES;
        self.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
        self.scrollEnabled = YES;
    }

}
return self;
}
```

Then set the class of your scroll view in IB to your custom subclass.  This will mean the content size is set automatically.

**This only works if you have one subview in the scroll view.**  Otherwise add create a new 'container view', put everything in it, then add this as the only subview to the scroll view.